# Show numpy array consists of rgb (255,255,255) as image, why it output pure black instead of pure white?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to generate a pure white image of size:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imshow
i = np.zeros((800,600,3))
i[:]=255
imshow(i)
```

I think this sets the rgb value to (255,255,255) so it should output to the screen all white. But on my machine it output all black instead.

I set i[:]=0. But it still output all black image.

Why is that?

Comment: Use proper datatype : `uint8, etc` before using imshow.

Comment: So what is the correct datatype for rgb? The doc at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imshow.html doesn't says any parameter.

Comment: your referenced documentation says nothing about colors or how the array is interpreted.  Does it change when the data is inhomogeneous (e.g., 0s and 255s)?

Comment: Have you tried i[:,:,:] = 255 ?

Comment: Use `i = np.zeros((800,600,3), dtype=np.uint8)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the dtype first. Use imshow(i.astype('uint8'))

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my solution was listed in this article below.  I had to add the vmin=0, vmax=255 options to imshow().  The clue for me was the comment by Elmar Peise above about non-homogeneity.

[Both 0 and 255 give black image for 'gray' color map, why is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66997469/both-0-and-255-give-black-image-for-gray-color-map-why-is-that)