# Both 0 and 255 give black image for 'gray' color map, why is that?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm trying to draw an image with matplotlib.

This code

```
im_data = np.full((100,100), 0)
axi = plt.imshow(im_data, cmap='gray')
```

gives me this

[image]

however, this code

```
im_data = np.full((100,100), 255)
axi = plt.imshow(im_data, cmap='gray')
```

gives me the exact black image as well.

Both 0 and 255 give black image for 'gray' color map, why is that?

I also tried `gray` and `binary` colormap and got the same results.

How do I have one of them rendered white image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your expected black/white output, you need to set `vmin` and `vmax` manually. Otherwise [**`pyplot.imshow()`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) infers the min/max from the data. Note that without setting these, any constant value would produce a black image, not just 0 and 255.

> **`vmin`, `vmax`:** float, optional
>
> ... By default, the colormap covers the complete value range of the supplied data ...

```py
im_data = np.full((100,100), 0)
axi = plt.imshow(im_data, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

[image: 0/255]

```py
im_data = np.full((100,100), 255)
axi = plt.imshow(im_data, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

[image: 255/255]